# How can I clone a Parse Query using the Javascript SDK on Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to clone queries because it helps me structure my code better. But, when I try to clone an query, I get an error saying: `Object [object Object] has no method 'skip'`. Here's the code I've tried:

```
var _ = require('cloud/modules/lodash'); // custom lodash 4.0.0
...
var query = new Query('Class');

var clonedQuery = _.clone(query);        // .cloneDeep() doesn't work either
clonedQuery.skip(i);                     // succeeds in unit tests but fails on cloud code
var clonedQuery.first();
```

Note: The underscore `_`  is actually lodash `4.0.0` that I've **manually bundled with my source code**, not the cloud module from Parse.

It's not clear to my why this is failing — it's lodash doing the cloning here, so there should be no difference between my local unit testing node  environment and the V8 Cloud Code environment.

---

EDIT: I was using Parse SDK 1.3.1 here. Solution is to upgrade. See below.

Comment: Just guessing, but how about `var clonedQuery = new Parse.Query(_.clone(query));`

Comment: Thanks for the comment — I actually learned that you can update the Parse JS SDK yourself. I had no idea! This solved the problem as per my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`_.clone()` actually does work for `Query` in Parse SDK 1.6.14, but not on 1.3.1, which I was using. I didn't know that you can manage the Parse JS SDK version yourself using the `parse jssdk` tool!

The solution for me was simply to update the SDK. See the discussion here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/171