# Underscores _.clone() does not work with Parse JS SDK compound queries

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, parse-server

I'm having trouble getting this to work in Parse Server v2.3.7 (which includes Parse JS SDK v1.9.2) with sorting a compound query. I can use ascending/descending query methods in the original query, but when I clone it they no longer work. Any ideas why this isn't working or is there a better approach to cloning the query?

```
var firstQuery = new Parse.Query('Object');
firstQuery.equalTo('property', 1);
var secondQuery = new Parse.Query('Object');
secondQuery.equalTo('property', 2);

var query = Parse.Query.or(firstQuery, secondQuery);
query.descending('updatedAt');
// This works
var clonedQuery = _.clone(query);
clonedQuery.ascending('updatedAt');
// Throws error "clonedQuery.ascending is not a function"
```

Continuing this issue: [How can I clone a Parse Query using the Javascript SDK on Parse Cloud Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888080/how-can-i-clone-a-parse-query-using-the-javascript-sdk-on-parse-cloud-code)

Comment: Ok, it is possible even with Underscore.js. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated

There is one thing Lodash.js does which Underscore.js doesn't. Lodash.js copy the prototype while Underscore.js sets `prototype` to `undefined`. To make it works with Underscore.js, you need to copy the prototype manually:

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var _ = require('underscore');

var firstQuery = new Parse.Query('Object');
firstQuery.equalTo('property', 1);
var secondQuery = new Parse.Query('Object');
secondQuery.equalTo('property', 2);

var query = Parse.Query.or(firstQuery, secondQuery);
query.descending('updatedAt');
// This works
var clonedQuery = _.clone(query);
Object.setPrototypeOf(clonedQuery, Object.getPrototypeOf(query)); // This line is very important!
clonedQuery.ascending('updatedAt');
// This works too
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually using underscore v1.8.3 and not lodash. I also just checked and, since I'm using parse-server, I'm actually using parse v1.9.2. Updating the question...

Comment: I'll give it a try in an isolated test outside of my existing code.

Comment: @enjoyjeremy. Ok, it is possible even with Underscore.js. I updated my answer.